# Error deploying project with SQL Server 2014 to Azure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, azure

I'm trying to deploy an ASP.NET MVC with SQL Server 2014 project to Azure. Upon deploying, I'm getting the following error:

> Web deployment task failed. (Could not deploy package.
>   Warning SQL0: A project which specifies SQL Server 2014 as the target platform may experience compatibility issues with Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12.
>   Warning SQL72030: The project and target databases have different collation settings. Deployment errors might occur.
>   Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 40517, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Keyword or statement option 'default_language' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.
>   Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
>   CREATE LOGIN [IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool]
>       FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = [us_english];

I've tried changing the authentication method in my local SSMS from Windows authentication to SQL Server, using username and password, but as I suspected it had no effect, since the connection string is overridden to use Azure's connection string anyway upon deployment.

Any idea how to solve this issue and deploy this database to Azure?

Comment: if you're using sql azure, then your database project should target sql azure, not sql 2014

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand?  It looks like you are attempting to deploy SQL 2014 to a 2012 target. Also many TSQL commands don't work on Azure such as default_language and **use xxx**.

Comment: @CamBruce I just checked, Azure does have a SQL 2014 on Windows Server 2012

Comment: The error message clearly states that the OP is targeting a SQL Azure DB, as in the PaaS service. You can run SQL 2014 in an Azure VM, sure, but this is not that case

Comment: This is not a DB project, it is an ASP.NET MVC app. I don't know how to change the DB version. Also, the database is generated by Fluent NHibernate.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Azure SQL Database, then your database project should target sql azure, not sql 2014. they support different feature sets.

To change in your database project, right click your DB project in Visual Studio and choose Properties, then under the project settings tab, change the `Target Platform` to `Microsoft Azure SQL Database V12`.

Comment: This is not a DB project, it is an ASP.NET MVC app.